# boost filesystem difficulties

Tags: c++, linker-errors, boost-filesystem

Hi I'm trying to use boost filesystem and am running into trouble when compiling. Below is the message from the console. I'm using boost 4.9 on OpenSuse 11.4 in eclipse. I have no idea what to try next to get this working so any help would be massively appreciated.
Thanks.

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/include/CGAL -L/usr/include/boost/iostreams -L/usr/include/gnuplot-iostream -L/usr/include/boost -L/usr/include -o"Aircraft_Engine_Noise"  ./src/Aircraft_Engine_Noise.o ./src/Environment_Functions.o ./src/Global.o ./src/Plotting.o ./src/Simulation.o ./src/filehandle.o ./src/gnuplot_i.o ./src/gridsquare.o ./src/nasagridsquare.o ./src/terrain.o ./src/user_input.o ./src/utils.o   -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
./src/Plotting.o: In function `boost::filesystem3::temp_directory_path()':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:537: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem3::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How did you install boost? Or did you get it from src and compile it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your compiler invocation. You are using `-L` for include directories, whereas you should use `-I`.

It also looks like you may not be linking to the `libboost_filesystem` library. It could be that problems with your erroneous invocation of `g++` are messing up the library search paths.

You may need to add the directory where the library is too. On my setup, it is in `/usr/local`, so

```
-L/usr/local
```

adds it to the library search path.

Comment: I thought I had done this. I added it to libraries. And the console line seems to show that: g++ -L/usr/include/CGAL -L/usr/include/boost/iostreams -L/usr/include/gnuplot-iostream -L/usr/include/boost -L/usr/include -o"Aircraft_Engine_Noise"  ./src/Aircraft_Engine_Noise.o ./src/Environment_Functions.o ./src/Global.o ./src/Plotting.o ./src/Simulation.o ./src/filehandle.o ./src/gnuplot_i.o ./src/gridsquare.o ./src/nasagridsquare.o ./src/terrain.o ./src/user_input.o ./src/utils.o   -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

Comment: That library *does* appear in the OP's linker invocation.

Comment: @wookie1 sorry, i hadn't seen the full invocation. There seem to be some errors in it, but they could be unrelated to your problem. Where exactly are the boost libs?

Comment: usr/include/boost is the file where all of the .hpp files are.

Comment: Then the libs should be in `/usr/lib`. Can you try fixing the problems with your invocation first?

Comment: @wookie1: .hpp files are not the libs, those are headers files.  `-I` is for telling the compiler where to find header files (including .hpp files) and `-L` is for library files, such as `libboost_filesystem.so`